# Limit contacts in "Assigned to" field of an activity to a specific group

Tags: custom-fields, activities

I need to limit available contacts in the "assigned to" field in a specific activity to only a specific group.

For example, I only want contacts in the "staff" group to be available as assigned to when creating certain activities - like meetings or phone calls.

We have had an issue with users accidentally "assigning" a scheduled phone call an external contact - like a politician or a funder - who should have been the person getting the call not the person making the call. An email getting sent to that person about the scheduled call is at best embarrassing or at worst a security issue if our notes about the call are getting sent to them.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is, I think, already an extension that will do this.  It's [here](https://civicrm.org/extensions/activity-assignee) and [here](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/assignee) and used by one of my (former) clients.  It's being actively used and cetainly works at 5.35.2 release level.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you will need to create a small extension with this functionality. You will be able to use the buildForm hook (https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_buildForm/) to alter the list of contacts.

Have you developed for CiviCRM before? If not, I would recommend walking through the Developer Guide (https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/).